# Detecting smile without taking photo

Tags: iphone, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, face-detection

I wonder if it is possible to check for face/smile/blink using `CIDetector`without taking photo?

You are just running `UIImagePickerController` and when face is found you display `UIAlert` or something else. I know I can take a photo and later check for detections but I'm curious if it is possible to avoid taking picture.

Thanks in advance for answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [SquareCam](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html), Apple's sample project for detecting facial features in real time using a camera. While it's a *bit* more complicated that just using a `UIImagePickerController`, it should be able to handle what you need. Hope that Helps!

Comment: Yep, this is what I was looking for... Is there any document explaining what is going on in this code? I have to admit that there is a lot of crazy stuff happening in this sample project :D

Comment: It's actually not too bad. There is a lot of comments, and the README file contains information on what each part does. Basically, for every frame, the app calls a method (`drawFaceBoxesForFeatures`) that looks for `CIFaceFeature` objects, and for every one it finds, it draw a red box around it.